Нужно ли тире в данном предлoжении?
Всё, что она могла, (—) это бежать вперёд и не останавливаться.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли в этом предложении тире на месте пропуска и как это можно объяснить?

Тире желательно поставить:
Всё, что она могла, — это бежать вперёд и не останавливаться.
Пояснение
Тире скорее интонационное и определяется по структуре предложения.
Предложение нестандартное, фразеологизированное.

При постановке знаков сложно указать правило, поэтому надо найти близкий стандартный вариант: Всё, что она могла,  так это бежать вперёд и не останавливаться.

Здесь тире не нужно, но при отсутствии слова так его желательно поставить.
Сходная тема: Единственное, что он хотел, так это выпить и закусить. Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Тире не требуется.
Похожие варианты:
Первое, что меня поразило, это пассажиры (худ. литература).
Кто хорош, так это Солженицын.
Что я хочу сделать — так это найти мой спиннинг.
Это вопрос-ответная модель предложения, см. тему.

Другой вариант — это простое предложение, тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным инфинитивами. Там ставится тире, а запятой закрывается придаточное.

